# Flexible height for rowspan

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to implement a basic grid list, but noticing that content is often greater in size then the row height.

Specifically in this example card titled Information.

The code was pre-generated by dashboard schematic and i just tweaked it.

I looked into rowHeight="fit" but that nothing.

Any way I can make rows heigh dynamic?

Code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4">
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]=1>
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Details
                        <button mat-icon-button class="edit-button">
                            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <pre>{{ itData| json }}</pre>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]=3>
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Card 2
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <div>Card Content Here</div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]=4>
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Information
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="toggleDetails()">{{ show ? 'Add IT' : 'View IT'}}</button>
                    <br>
                    <section *ngIf="!show">
                        <sc-it-new></sc-it-new>
                    </section>
                    <section *ngIf="show">
                        <sc-it-table></sc-it-table>
                    </section>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatGridList is not a layout component. It is a "grid" component. A "grid" means all the columns and all rows have the same width or height. So the intent of grid list is to make all of its tiles the same size. It is not the right choice of component if you are trying to lay out content flexibly.

Despite that, I don't think it is possible to do what you want anyway. It is possible to dynamically change the number of columns or the width:height ratio of the tiles, but not for certain rows or columns only.

Comment: Please share your solution to help others that are facing the same problem.